# Could I clone a Kubernetes minion with vmware

Tags: vmware, clone, docker

My question is not "Can I clone a docker minion" but rather, will this somehow mess up the Kubernetes Master.

We have 4 Kubernetes Minions. I want a 5th. My plan is to clone the 4th Minion, rename it to 5, start the vm without networking, change 2 or 3 of the necessary config files like kubeconfig, reboot the vm and connect the network again.

However my ACTUAL question is this: will the pods already on Minion 4 that have now been cloned to 5 cause any issues when it connects to the Master, or will the master simply see they are not needed and clear them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a ReplicaSet configured for your Pods, you can safely shut down the node before cloning and the pods on it will be replicated across other active worker nodes in the cluster.

Make sure to clean any node-specific configurations on node 5 after cloning and  before joining this new worker node to the cluster. VMware should generate new MAC address for the NIC.